# Error "Unrecognized database format" when opening a .mdb file

Tags: microsoft-office, libreoffice, microsoft-access, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-base

I have a .mdb file which I do not know which version of ms access was used to create it. When I try to open it, I get "Unrecognized database format" error. I tried using MS ACCESS 2003 and 2007 and libreOffice x86 and x64 versions. The similar questions here in the forum have few answers and they do not solve the problem. And that's what [toolsley.com/file.html] showed , `"raw data (format not in libmagic database)"`. And that's what I got using HxD editor
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm9m1.jpg . Is there a way to open it?

Answer (score 0):

The .mdb format has been deprecated since 2003. If the file is valid, though, LibreOffice **with Base installed** should be able to open the file and convert it to a number of other formats.

However, if the file is mislabeled (i.e., is **not** Microsoft MDB Access file), it might need another application to open it, once the file type has been identified. If the file is damaged, it might not be possible to salvage it.

To identify the file type, open it in a hex editor such as the free [HxD Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/), and examine the first few fields. From [Positron Developer's Guide: MDB File Format](https://xiph.org/positron/doc/mdb.html), "The MDB file begins with a variable length header describing the overall database configuration. The header is followed by one or more variable length records. Every MDB file must have (generally as its first record, though it is not clear if this location is a requirement) a null record." You could also use a third-party tool such as [TriD](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/936/) or [alternative application or online service](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/what-file-is-that-how-to-identify-unrecognized-files-types-and-format/) to identify it. *Caveat:* check any application in [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload), and beware sending sensitive data to an online service.

Comment: That's what I got using HxD editor...
[https://imgur.com/a/5lf0hGu]

Comment: And that's what [https://www.toolsley.com/file.html] showed...
**raw data (format not in libmagic database)**.

Comment: @Eslam, You can edit a question,rather than put your findings as an answer. Since you cannot determine the file type, the best you might do is to walk through the file to see if any data makes sense as part of a database. Note that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures has no filetype signature of "FILLING ITEM".

Comment: I know it's a database file because I tried opening the file using libre calc and showed a data in a table. I just do not know what database file it's. Is it a MS ACCESS file or SQL SERVER file or else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Vista and up, you may have a system backup.

Right-click the file and select Restore Previous Versions.

If this does not work, try the solution mentioned in the below guide:

[Solved: Unrecognized Database format Error](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/178965-how-to-fix-microsoft-access-unrecognized-database-format-error)

You could try creating a new empty MDB file and importing the objects from the old one. It might work at least for some of the objects.

Best Regards,
Alice